# XSLT Sort nested xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to sort the below XML from SAP based on E1EDP01 - POSEX and ACTION, rest of the xml should be copied as it is. Please note that there's E1EDP19 under E1EDP01, which should be copied as it is as well. My XSLT is not working  bcoz am not sure what should be the value for the template match. Please help.

```
<ORDERS05>
 <IDOC BEGIN="1">

 <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>014</QUALF>
        <ORGID>PF01</ORGID>
    </E1EDK14>


 <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <POSEX>00020</POSEX>
        <ACTION>001</ACTION>
        <PSTYP>0</PSTYP>
        <MENGE>540.000</MENGE>
        <MENEE>RO</MENEE>
       <E1EDP19>
          <Text> Test 2 </Text>
        </E1EDP19>
 </E1EDP01>
 <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
        <POSEX>00030</POSEX>
        <ACTION>001</ACTION>
        <PSTYP>1</PSTYP>
        <MENGE>140.000</MENGE>
        <MENEE>AD</MENEE>
        <E1EDP19>
          <Text> Test 1 </Text>
        </E1EDP19>
 </E1EDP01>

 <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
        <SUMID>002</SUMID>
        <SUMME>832.2</SUMME>
        <SUNIT>USD</SUNIT>
    </E1EDS01>

</IDOC>
</ORDERS05>


 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <!--                                                --> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!--                                                --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--                                                --> 
 <xsl:template match="E1EDP01">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="POSEX">
    <xsl:sort select="POSEX" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


  Expected Result

  <ORDERS05>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">

  <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>014</QUALF>
    <ORGID>PF01</ORGID>
    </E1EDK14>

    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
      <POSEX>00030</POSEX>
      <ACTION>001</ACTION>
     <PSTYP>1</PSTYP>
    <MENGE>140.000</MENGE>
    <MENEE>AD</MENEE>
    <E1EDP19>
      <Text> Test 1 </Text>
    </E1EDP19>
 </E1EDP01>


  <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <POSEX>00020</POSEX>
    <ACTION>001</ACTION>
    <PSTYP>0</PSTYP>
    <MENGE>540.000</MENGE>
    <MENEE>RO</MENEE>
   <E1EDP19>
      <Text> Test 2 </Text>
    </E1EDP19>
  </E1EDP01>


  <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMID>002</SUMID>
    <SUMME>832.2</SUMME>
    <SUNIT>USD</SUNIT>
  </E1EDS01>

 </IDOC>
 </ORDERS05>
```

Comment: So which result do you want for that input sample you have posted? There are two `E1EDP01`, aren't they already sorted on `POSEX` and `ACTION`?

Comment: sort descending.  <POSEX>00030</POSEX> should come before  <POSEX>00020</POSEX>

Comment: Please show us at least your desired outcome, and - at best - an approach of yours trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the `E1EDP01` elements then by using `xsl:sort` in an `xsl:apply-templates` of a template processing the children of the parent element:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[E1EDP01]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::E1EDP01)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                         <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:sort select="POSEX" order="descending"/>
                            <xsl:sort select="ACTION" order="descending"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCT9/1 has an online example.

Comment: When I run this, I get the error  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group'

Comment: The question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 so I have posted an XSLT 2.0 solution which then of course requires an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 which is available for Java on Maven and Sourceforge.

Comment: Thanks. But Is there a way to achieve the same result with XSLT 1.0?